# Image not overlapping on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Hi guys so i have a simple image and then i have a button which overlaps it and its working fine on all platforms, however for some reason it dosen't work at all on IE or my iphone when i launch my site. The button just sits to the right of the picture , I have no idea why IE does this but if anyone can help me fix the bug on it, it would be great

HTML:

```
  <div class="aboutpic">
    <img src="Images/back2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    <a href="CV.pdf" button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Download Resume</a>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.btn-warning {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 198, 0, 0.9);
  border: 0;
  padding: 23px;
  border-radius: 34px;
  line-height: 0.428571;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
}

.aboutpic {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 59px;

}
```

Again this works perfectly in google , chrome and mobiles etc but not iN IE or my iphone 6+ and i really have no clue how to fix it

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answer states, flex is not supported in IE. IF you use `position:absolute` you can easily center the text with translate and positions

Also your HTML was not correct ( the button inside the a ), because

1. you didn't open / close the button tags.
2. nesting button inside `a` is not valid html

see below

```css
.btn-warning {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 198, 0, 0.9);
  border: 0;
  padding: 23px;
  border-radius: 34px;
  line-height: 0.428571;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
-ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.aboutpic {
 position:relative;
 text-align:center;

}
```

```html
<div class="aboutpic">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img-responsive">
    <a href="CV.pdf" class="btn btn-warning">Download Resume</a>
  </div>
```

or > [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/03nojnwd/3/)

Comment: That worked , i had to change some things about but it worked fine :) i just want to say that I hate IE with a passion and i cant wait for it not to be used anymore , thanks again xxxx

Answer (score 1):

flex is not supported in IE 10, you must use -ms-flex instead.

Comment: Still has not fixed it, the button is still not overlapping the image

Comment: why do you position the button absolute when you use flexbox?

Comment: Like i said , i have an Image , and then i use flexbox to center it in the middle of the div, i then use position absolute on the button to overlap it onto the div, so it sits ontop of it

Comment: cant see where you position your button... try top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;margin:auto;